How to use track changes in MS Word with Python after Azure OpenAI API model 3.5 has corrected the document?
I am trying to have OpenAI to check for spelling and grammar when someone is uploading a document. I don't want the model 3.5 to make the changes directly. I want it to change it with track changes and create a new output file so the user can download that file and accept or denied the changes themselves.
I have tried everyting????
